# Disabling the implicit this in C++

Tags: c++

I've been handed a legacy C++ application to patch and add some new features, and I'm having a terrible time following some of the code, as it makes fairly extensive use of globals, huge `#define` macros and many *extremely* tersely named variables/functions (3 letter functions from 2 inheritance levels up, etc...). As such, determining the source of many of the functions or variables is rater challenging.

It also uses Hungarian notation.... *sometimes* (`m_Thingie` is a member variable, but sometimes so is `thingie`).

Is there any way to make it so class member access without specifying `this->` fails? That would let me use the compiler to effectively determine variable source.

I don't mind if it's a horrible hack, if I can turn it on for a little while when doing refactoring, and then off for any release compilation, that would be fine.

Comment: Better use the "Go To Definition"-feature of your editor instead I would say.

Comment: Can your IDE not help you here? Usual right click follow symbol/take me to definition etc.

Comment: @PhilCK, @ BaummitAugen - It helps, certainly, but having to do it for basically 1/2 the variables on screen at any time is somewhat prohibitive. I'm trying to improve the maintainability in the long term, not work around the issue for the moment.

Comment: Pick an IDE with _advanced_ colorization. Parameters, local variables and class members may have different colors. Well of course also macros. I have no idea of globals but I'd guess too

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti - Interesting. Any suggestions? I'm using VS2013 with ReSharper now, and if it can do that, I don't know how to enable it. Maybe this'll get me to finally learn Emacs/Vim.

Answer (score 1):

Pick an IDE with *advanced* colorization, Visual Studio can do it then if you're already using it you don't need to *learn* anything else.

1. Click **Tools** menu then click **Options**.
2. Expand **Environment** settings group from the list in the left and select **Fonts and Colors**.

[image: Fonts and colors dialog]

3. Scroll down **Display items** in the right panel until you find `C++ ...` items. There you can change settings for things you need (and more):
4. Change settings to highlight variables and functions according to your needing. Be aware that you can change only color (background and foreground) but size is shared. Too many colors will confuse you then you may need to make some tests before you find *right* combination for you.

Final result *may* be:

[image]

In this example you can see different colors for:

1. Local variables.
2. Global functions (anything declared outside a class).
3. Function parameters.
4. Member functions (you may also set a different color for `static` member functions).
5. Fields (you may also set a different color for `static` class fields).
6. Global variables.
7. Macros.

Of course literals (string, characters and *numbers*), user types and enumerations can have their own color combination (also specialized for templates). When you're done with refactoring you can restore default settings clicking on **Use Defaults**.